# Power manager keeps shutting down the display

Tags: 10.10, display, power-management

I'm probably missing something here. I'm using the default Ubuntu power manger, I set it up like this:

- On AC: no screen dimming when idle, never put computer to sleep, never put display to sleep.
- On battery: I kept the default settings.

Still, Ubuntu does whatever it likes, and after 15 min it puts the display to sleep.

Does anyone have the same problem and found a way to solve it? I'm using an Eee PC with Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop.

Comment: No, don't have that problem. A week idea: Is there a BIOS-setting?

Comment: tried that out, there is no power management options in the bios.

Comment: Does it help at all if you click the Make Default button in Power Management Preferences? Also, what is the output of `cat /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/AC/state`?

Comment: cat gave me: `cat: /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/AC/state: No such file or directory` , and make default didn't help either

Comment: sorry about the late answer, i did found out what the problem is,
it is a BIOS setting that i still don't have an idea how to change,
will post if i will find how to change it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, after ages of searching what might be the problem i found out that it was the screen saver. I believe it was by default set to go black after 15 minutes, it had nothing to do with the power management just go to system > screensaver to disable it

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Action" tab in "OnAC" tab, which sets the screen to sleep mode after 10 minutes and power off after 15 minutes.